# Send email via firebase functions with hostgator accounts

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble sending emails through firebase functions, the mail account is from hostgator, I have done tests locally and it sends it without problem but when I upload the function to firebase the emails do not reach the destination and in the logs there are no errors, what could be happening?

The configuration is as follows:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport ({
     host: ‘mail.example.com’,
     port: 587,
     secure: false,
     auth: {
         user: 'info@example.com’,
         pass: ‘password’
     },
     tls: {
         ciphers: ‘SSLv3’
     },
     debug: true
});
```

I have even tried other settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following snipet:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
admin.initializeApp();

/**
* Here we're using Gmail to send 
*/
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'yourgmailaccount@gmail.com',
        pass: 'yourgmailaccpassword'
    }
});

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
      
        // getting dest email by query string
        const dest = req.query.dest;

        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'Your Account Name <yourgmailaccount@gmail.com>', // Something like: Jane Doe <janedoe@gmail.com>
            to: dest,
            subject: 'I\'M A PICKLE!!!', // email subject
            html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">Pickle Riiiiiiiiiiiiiiiick!!</p>
                <br />
                <img src="https://images.prod.meredith.com/product/fc8754735c8a9b4aebb786278e7265a5/1538025388228/l/rick-and-morty-pickle-rick-sticker" />
            ` // email content in HTML
        };
  
        // returning result
        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
            if(erro){
                return res.send(erro.toString());
            }
            return res.send('Sended');
        });
    });    
});
```

I have taken it from [this page](https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e) where you can find the whole tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can see on the cPanel email configs:

```
let mailerConfig = {
  service: "mail.DOMAIN.com",
  host: "mail.DOMAIN.com",
  secureConnection: true,
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: EMAIL,
    pass: PASSWORD,
  },
};
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailerConfig);
```

Also, you can try to configure the firbase trigger:
[Firebase Email Trigger](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email)